# Listing users with access to a file with python

Tags: python, windows

I'm curious if there's a function that would allow me to access the security properties of a file with Python.
Say, when you right-click on a file and select properties, then go to the Security Tab.

[image]

I'd like to get the list under "Group or usernames."

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Added the `windows` tag, as the entire idea that a file has "security properties" of this sort is OS-specific. Linux handles this completely differently (in the standard UNIX way).

Answer (score 0):

For these sorts of tasks, you can use the win32security module

Here's an example of getting the user list

```
import os, sys
import win32security
path = "C:\\Users\\lucas\\Desktop\\perfil.jpeg"
fs = win32security.GetFileSecurity(path,win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
dacl = fs.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
ace_count = dacl.GetAceCount()

for i in range(ace_count):
    _, _, usersid = dacl.GetAce(i)
    account, domain, typecode = win32security.LookupAccountSid(None, usersid)
    print(domain + u'\\' + account)
```

Output:

```
BUILTIN\Users
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
BUILTIN\Administrators
DESKTOP\lucas
```

Comment: I am not able to install the win32security package. I'm using PyCharm as my IDE, and it says installation complete when I install it, but it still doesn't recognize the module while running the code. Do you have any input on how to correctly install this package?